# Using HTTPS for DTD

Tags: xml, plist, doctype, dtd

Someone just opened a pull request for one of my projects to alter the document type for any XML Apple Property List file to use `https://`, changing them from:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

to:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "https://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

Am I wrong in thinking this is a useless change? I've never seen an XML file use a `https://` document type URI before.

Comment: Is it a useless change? Being HTTPS the certificate, and thus the server identity will be checked.

Comment: @Richard Right, but do there actually exist any situations where this is useful? Generally any property list parsers will already know the file's format, and will not need to access the DTD. I've never seen an XML document using a HTTPS doctype URI, and any property list created using Apple's tools or programmatically using Apple's APIs contain the original doctype.

Comment: My failure to think of an attack vector by supplying an invalid DTD does not mean there isn't one.

Comment: @Richard I understand what you're saying, and I realise I may sound obtuse, but when I consider the ramifications of this being a security issue, I cannot believe it. Any Xcode project that has not been hand-edited would be vulnerable (and I can't find a single resource advising developers to hand-modify any property lists). w3.org [does not even serve the HTML DTDs over HTTPS](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd), so any web page that specifies a doctype URI is insecure.

Comment: There is a general truism in cryptography: "anyone can design a cryptographic algorithm they cannot break". The subtext is that someone else may well be able to. My thesis is that this applies to security in general: just because I cannot see a way to exploit something says nothing about other's ability to do so. With respect to other projects: security threats evolve, new attack vectors are found. An existing application template including with an SDK may have been fine when it was created, but that doesn't mean it is safe now. The push may be paranoid: but are you paranoid enough?

Comment: Have you considered asking the author of the pull request?